# Tips and Tricks in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I want to gather Dreamweaver Tips and Tricks making development easy.

Mine, I recently discovered that I could asign a keyboard key in inserting code from 'code snippet'. for me it's really a time and effort saver. Since I would just press the special key and code is generated.

How about yours? What are your techniques?

Thanks!

Comment: #1: Don't use Dreamweaver (HHOS :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Dreamweaver since 1.0. Whilst it used to be a great web development tool it seems to have declined and become almost irrelevant, see [Dreamweaver is dying](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2009/03/05/dreamweaver-is-dying/).

> The real problem for Dreamweaver and for its users is that the nature of the web is changing dramatically. Dynamically-generated web applications, from Amazon right down to the humble blog, all offer much more – in-built commenting, voting, RSS feeds, etc – than the best sites built on static HTML can ever hope to provide.

I actually find that Dreamweaver now makes web development harder.

Comment: I wouldn't say harder. But "running late" with the current speed of changes in the web, Yes. But its still the best Visual HTML/CSS editor i ever used. By the way a good substitute for DW in that point? Suggestions?

Comment: Well I still use Dreamweaver so cannot offer any good alternatives. Yes, the visual editor is very good. This has always been a strength of the product. It just seems that it's not the all-round authoring tool it used to be. I've had to adopt products like oXygen to do the heavy XML lifting.

Comment: Same as Gerard, I still use Dreamweaver! Since I only use Dreamweaver I can't compare to other IDE. I hope Dreamweaver will support API w/ docs.

Comment: I think it's not only that, but poor coding on the part of the DW development team, also; the app is really quite buggy and releases are pushed out only with a view to making money as quickly as possible rather than the support of the customer.  The only reason I use this application now is to support Classic ASP apps.

Comment: Damn! I didn't check the date - this is a really old thread!  lol!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't touch Dreamweaver with a ten-foot pole. What exactly drives you to use Dreamweaver over a tool such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)? Most developers nowadays are comfortable with simple syntax highlighting, which Notepad++ supports right out of the box, with the addition of a built-in FTP client. You get a lot more, minus the $400 you need to pay to attain features that are available in every other IDE for free.

Comment: I'm kinda embarrassed to know that there are few/no user of DW here.. hehe, What I like about DW is there File and Site Manager and I think I got used to using DW, because when I started I used DW. I would like to hear some good alternative of DW.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment or I would reply to yours, Pennf0lio. When I did web development a few years ago, I used DreamWeaver *solely* for the Site Manager tool. I loved knowing how easily I could move a file and not break anything that referenced it.

That said, I still used Vim to actually develop the sites.